# what is the internal working of code quality check tools?

Tags: findbugs, checkstyle, pmd

On which principal do the code quality check tools work?

For example PMD, FindBugs, CheckStyle etc.

Do they use some kind of computer science principals?

Comment: They're all open source. Do you have a specific question about something they're doing in that source?

Comment: Not a specific question but wanted to ask how do they analyze the code?

Comment: This question may not be [a perfect match](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO ... we'll see what gives.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, FindBugs is the result of [David H. Hovemeyer's PhD thesis](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1123680). The [FindBugs documentation](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/publications.html) also lists several more papers.